# Seeding a value object. Best way to do that. .NET 6 with EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have an entity `Product` and a ValueObject `Money`.

```
public class Product
{
    public Product() { }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public Money Price { get; set; }
}

public class Money : BaseValueObject
{
    public Money(string currency, decimal amount)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(currency)) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(currency));

        this.Currency = currency;
        this.Amount   = amount;
    }

    public string Currency { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount  { get; private set; }

    protected override IEnumerable<object?> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Currency;
        yield return Amount;
    }
}
```

I set up a table configuration in this way:

```
public class ProductEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Products");
        builder.HasKey(product => product.Id);

        builder.Property(product => product.Name)
               .HasColumnName("Name");

        builder.OwnsOne(product => product.Price,
            navigationBuilder =>
            {
                navigationBuilder.Property(money => money.Amount)
                                 .HasColumnName("Price");
                navigationBuilder.Property(money => money.Currency)
                                 .HasColumnName("Currency");
            });
    }
}

public class ProductContext : DbContext
{
    public ProductContext(DbContextOptions<ProductContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ProductEntityTypeConfiguration());

        // seeding
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(p =>
        {
            p.HasData(
                new Product { Id = 1, Name = "cola" },
                new Product { Id = 2, Name = "chips" },
                new Product { Id = 3, Name = "candy" }
            );
            p.OwnsOne(p => p.Price).HasData(
                new Money("EUR", 100),
                new Money("EUR", 050),
                new Money("EUR", 065)
            );
        });
    }
```

Since `Money` is a valueObject, it has no keys. I would expect with this configuration to store instead of 1 price field, 2 fields: one named "Price" and another "Currency", in the same Product table.

The configuration runs correctly but as the "seeding" executes I get:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The seed entity for entity type 'Money' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'ProductId'.'

Don't understand why it's asking for the `ProductId`. So what is the correct way to seed a ValueObject ?

I'm using .NET 6 and EF Core 6.

Comment: Owned types are modelled as foreign key relationships, saved to the same table. So the PK `Product.Id` and the shadow property `Money.ProductId` are mapped to the same table PK. You need to use an anonymous type to seed shadow properties `new { ProductId = 1, Currency = "EUR", Amount = 100) }, ...` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data

Comment: Makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

For owned entity types for tracking needs a [primary key is created as a shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#implicit-keys) for the owned type. The value of the key of an instance of the owned type will be the same as the value of the key of the owner instance.

You can specify value for it to [seed the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data) using anonymous object:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>(p =>
{
    p.HasData(
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "cola" },
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "chips" },
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "candy" }
    );
    p.OwnsOne(pr => pr.Price)
        .HasData(
            new { ProductId = 1, Currency = "EUR", Amount = 100m },
            new { ProductId = 2, Currency = "EUR", Amount = 050m },
            new { ProductId = 3, Currency = "EUR", Amount = 065m }
        );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could make a static class with following methods:

```cs
public class ProductEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        // ...

        builder.OwnsOne(product => product.Price,
            navigationBuilder =>
            {
                // ...
                DataSeeder.Seed(navigationBuilder)
            });

        DataSeeder.Seed(builder);
    }

    private class DataSeeder
    {
        private static readonly List<Product> Products = new()
        {
            new Product { Name = "cola", Price = { Currency = "EUR", Amount = 100m } },
            new Product { Name = "chips", Price = { Currency = "EUR", Amount = 100m } },
            new Product { Name = "candy", Price = { Currency = "EUR", Amount = 100m } }
        }

        public static void Seed(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
        {
            builder.HasData(Products.Select((p, i) => new
            {
                ProductId = i + 1,
                p.Name,
            }));
        }

        public static void Seed(OwnedNavigationBuilder<Product, Money> builder)
        {
            builder.HasData(Products.Select((p, i) => new
            {
                ProductId = i + 1,
                p.Price.Currency,
                p.Price.Amount,
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

This seems more readable for me and you don't have to specify ids explicitly.